# Using SQL generate pivot table

Tags: sql, oracle

i'm trying to learn using SQL to generate pivot table. But no matter how i try i keep getting **ORA-00936: missing expression** error from oracle.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT HOS_PAY_ID, AMOUNT FROM HOSPITAL_PAYMENT)
PIVOT (SUM (AMOUNT) FOR AMOUNT IN ([10000],[8000],[7000],[9000],[11000],[13000]) AS TEST
ORDER BY HOS_PAY_ID;
```

and this is my data:

[image]

Thank You.

Comment: Is that supposed to be Oracle syntax? Those square brackets may not be expected?

Comment: I removed `sql-server` tag based on error message. After @jarlh comment not too sure... Please tag your question correctly, don't tag products not involved

Comment: what should i replace for those bracket in oracle

Comment: [PIVOT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm#CHDCEJJE) in Oracle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
     SELECT HOS_PAY_ID, AMOUNT 
     FROM HOSPITAL_PAYMENT
)
PIVOT (
        SUM (AMOUNT) FOR AMOUNT IN (10000,8000,7000,9000,11000,13000)
      )
ORDER BY HOS_PAY_ID;
```